Poor sound quality recording off the Behringer 2442 USB interface
I'm trying to record my band using the USB output port into my laptop using Audacity.
When I record I check the mic levels are high but the recordings are awful -  it only seems to pick-up the lead guitar and lead vocals, but the lead guitarvis really tinny, with almost no bass, drums or rhythm guitar.
I was expecting the full front of house sound to come through - anyone got any tips on how improve the recordings?
I don't need individual tracks, a single track with us all on is fine.
Not sure if this is a mixer issue or DAW issue.

You’ve left a lot out. How are your mics set up?
